# Possible to build Windows drivers using Visual Studio 2019 Build Tools + SDK + WDK without using the EWDK ISO?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, wdk

We're trying to build some Windows driver (on Windows 10 Enterprise) from within Jenkins. To do that, we were using the Visual Studio 2019 Build Tools, installed the SDK and the WDK as described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/download-the-wdk

Doing that will always result in the following error message:

```
error MSB8020: The build tools for WindowsKerne
lModeDriver10.0 (Platform Toolset = 'WindowsKernelModeDriver10.0') cannot be found. To build using the WindowsKernelModeDriver10.0 build tools, please install WindowsKerne
lModeDriver10.0 build tools.  Alternatively, you may upgrade to the current Visual Studio tools by selecting the Project menu or right-click the solution, and then selecti
ng "Retarget solution".
```

Doing the same on a PC where Visual Studio is installed will work.

The interesting part is:
Using the .iso image linked on the page, where Microsoft claims that it would include the VS2019 build tools + SDK + WDK, works as well.

Now I do not want to use that ISO file, as we already have the Visual Studio build tools installed on our Jenkins machines - for building other C++ software.

Is there any known solution available to just extend an existing build tools 2019 installation to allow building Windows drivers?

Comment: download the eWDK ISO, it includes all tools/SDK/WDK to build drivers : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/download-the-wdk#enterprise-wdk-ewdk-for-windows-server-2022

Comment: that's why I wrote "Now I do not want to use that ISO file..."

Comment: but this is the supported way